# jQuery change event (to monitor form for updates)

Tags: jquery, forms, events

I'm monitoring form input elements for change (to alert the user of unsaved form changes on page exit).

It is my understanding that the jQuery change event is triggered only once certain input elements lose focus (for instance, a text box).

This is problematic though, since the user could edit a single text box, then try to exit, and the text box change event wouldn't fire.

Here is how far I've gotten:

```
var formChanges = {
    override: false,
    changed: false,
    checkChanges: function() {
        if(!formChanges.override) {
           if(formChanges.changed) {
               return "There are currently unsaved changes.";
           }
        }
    },
    init: $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkThis').submit(function() { //'checkThis' is the form ID
           formChanges.override = true;
       });
       $(':input').change(function() {
           formChanges.changed = true;
       });
    })
}
window.onbeforeunload = formChanges.checkChanges;
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually for what you are doing i think you are better off using keypress or keyup for inputs and change for select and radio like this

```
   $('input:text, textarea').keypress(function() {
       formChanges.changed = true;
   });

   $('select, input:radio, input:checkbox').change(function(){
       formChanges.changed = true;
   });
```

Comment: I don't think every keypress necessarily means a change in the text (arrow keys).

Comment: well of course knowing if something has changed is much more complex than what i did (you should actually check the actual value against the orginal value, adding a letter and deleting it doesn't change an input).  My answer was only about choosing the right event, and i think that you should use keypress and not change for text inputs.

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work pretty well:

```
var oldForm = null;
function monitorChanges(form) {
    if(oldForm == null) {
        oldForm = ($(form).serialize());
    } else {
        alert(oldForm == $(form).serialize());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a "hack" would be focus on an un-related element when unload before checkChanges. A keypress doesn't really mean a change.

Edit: like Nicola said, to make absolutely sure if it's changed or not, you'll probably need to compare to original values.

Comment: This is pretty clever. Thanks for the idea!